# Generating multiple reports consisting of subreports

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have created a report that shows information concerning all data about specific server (fig.1).
Report is made of few subreports, and it is generated when user picks specific server and click generate report button. Subreports are generated based on parametric queries.
Is there any way to made Access to generate that kind of report for all servers at once? I have already tried to change the subreports queries so they shows all records, but in that case main report does not look as it supposed to (fig.2).

[image: Fig.1]
[image: Fig.2]

I want to get a multiple reports, as shown in fig.1, generated automatically for all servers and placed in one pdf file.

Comment: Do you have surbreport container control Master/Child Links set? This is not a programming issue. Perhaps you should post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: Thanks, that actually solves the problem. Tables from those subreports are connected with many-to-many relation, but that is just another subreport added with no visibility property on it.